# Content/Mime type detection of office files is always resulting application/x-tika-ooxml

Tags: java, mime-types, apache-tika

I am trying to detect the mime types based on file input stream, with no information available with respect to file extension.

I am using Tika 2.1.0.

However for a office file like for instance spreadsheet content type detection is always resulting in "application/x-tika-ooxml" instead of "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet".

I tried even wrapping the input stream in TikaInputStream but still same result.

```
public class TikaMimeDetector {
    public static void detectMimeType(InputStream stream) {
        Tika tika = new Tika();
        try {
            TikaInputStream tikaStream = TikaInputStream.get(stream);
            String mimeType = tika.detect(tikaStream);
            System.out.println("Mime type is " + mimeType);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And maven dependency as below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-parsers-standard-package</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: For container aware detection, needed to get the subtype of OOXML files, you will need to supply a `TikaInputStream`

Comment: Tried this using TikaInputStream , still having same issue

TikaInputStream tikaStream = TikaInputStream.get(stream); 
String mimeType = tika.detect(tikaStream);

Comment: You'd get that behaviour if you were missing the detector jars or their dependencies - try following the steps in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/Troubleshooting+Tika#TroubleshootingTika-IdentifyingwhatDetectorsyourTikainstallsupports ?

Comment: I'm getting the correct answer as long as I include tika-parsers-standard-package even without using a TikaInputStream.  I did just notice a, um, feature that will be fixed in the next release of 2.x where tika-ooxml would be detected if the content-type file wasn't stored within the first few entries in the physical zip file...standard behavior for MSOffice created files.  However, you'd get tika-ooxml on files that were created by POI or OpenOffice or other non-MSOffice created files.  If you're able to share the file, I can look.

Comment: File is of type Spread sheet(which is similar to xlsx file) and is created using add google sheet option in GoogleDrive, which has few plain text inside sheet. Tika gives content type as application/x-tika-ooxml. When tried to parse this file to determine content. its not able to parse content properly.

AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
parser.parse(tikaStream, handler, metadata);
System.out.println(handler.toString());

Comment: Additional to above comment,
if i pass Mime type as "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" during parsing of file, than it gives correct content present in spread sheet.